# will vpn be able to intercept all traffic over a socket bound to another network interface

Tags: networking, network-programming, vpn, tunnel

VPNs like Cisco any-connect normally route all traffic through their own network interface.

Would such VPNs still be able to route all traffic even if one binds a socket(client socket in my case) from an app to another network interface.

Comment: My assumption is that, if you have your internet (and VPN) connection on `eth0` and a local LAN on `eth1`, you should be able to communicate with your local nodes without the VPN interfering, e.g. with `ping -I eth1 <LAN machine IP>`. Makes sense to me, but I would love to see some real answer...

Comment: Not very sure but Cisco AnyConnect VPN regularly monitors the routing table and changes it to how it wants it as soon as it detects a change to make sure all traffic is routed via its own interface. Unfortunately i don't have the required environment to test it out. I am just hoping specifically bounding my client socket to a particular network interface avoids this.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to make a VPN, but you can view most of them as having three primary components

1. A tunnel interface - a virtual network interface that is listed along with your real network interfaces (on linux you should see in `ip link show`). The interface implements a protocol that abstracts all the links between the VPN client and server to make it seem like they are on a simpler network
2. A routing rule - a routing rule that tells your computer what data to send through the tunneling interface and what packets to send through your normal network interfaces. This rule can be as simple as **send all packets through the tunneling interface**
3. A cryptographic algorithm - the method of making sure the packets are encrypted and is normally abstracted by the tunneling interface

So to answer your question, you still have access to the other network interfaces. As long you you can bind to it (layer 2 API calls) or listen to it (layer 3 routing rules) then you can access it in a useful way. I recommend looking at your routing table after the VPN is established to get a better idea of what is going on.